# JS How to hide all categorys at page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work with categorys at web page, an i build next view to show categories. And i create one solution how to categorize all data in app.

But i have issues which i cant resolve.

So problem is, when i first time open my web page, all categories from list visible, and i want, categories need only visible after *category items* press.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

    $('.category_item').click(function () {
        var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');
        console.log(catProduct);

        $('.category_item').removeClass('ct_item-active');
        $(this).addClass('ct_item-active');

        $('.product-item').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
        function hideProduct() {
            $('.product-item').hide();
        } setTimeout(hideProduct, 400);

        function showProduct() {
            $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').show();
            $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
        } setTimeout(showProduct, 400);
    });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrap > h1 {
    color: #494B4D;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.wrap > h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C7C7C7;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.store-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
}

.category_list .category_item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #E84C3D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.category_list .ct_item-active {
    background: #2D3E50;
}

.products-list {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.products-list .product-item {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
    transition: all .4s;
}

.products-list .product-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.products-list .product-item a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #2D3E50;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="store-wrapper">
        <div class="category_list">
            <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Technical">Technical</a>
            <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Organizational">Organizational</a>

        </div>
        <section class="products-list">
            <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Equipment</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Tool</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-item" category="Organizational">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Material</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as u can see i don't have func which show all categorys at main page.
But when i reload page all categorys is visible, at this moment i'ts 3, but i have more then 3, **and i want to show this categorys after pressing category items.**

Comment: which `button`? I can't see any `button` in your `html`?

Comment: @randomSoul sorry, i name my **category_list** like button

Comment: Instead Of $(document).ready(function () Use $("your-button").click(function ()

Comment: @Manish i try it, not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need add `.products-list .product-item { display:none}` to your css.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.category_list .category_item[category="all"]').addClass('ct_item-active');

    $('.category_item').click(function () {
        var catProduct = $(this).attr('category');
        console.log(catProduct);

        $('.category_item').removeClass('ct_item-active');
        $(this).addClass('ct_item-active');

        $('.product-item').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
        function hideProduct() {
            $('.product-item').hide();
        } setTimeout(hideProduct, 400);

        function showProduct() {
            $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').show();
            $('.product-item[category="' + catProduct + '"]').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
        } setTimeout(showProduct, 400);
    });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrap > h1 {
    color: #494B4D;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.wrap > h1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C7C7C7;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.store-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
}

.category_list .category_item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #E84C3D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.category_list .ct_item-active {
    background: #2D3E50;
}

.products-list {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.products-list .product-item {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
    transition: all .4s;
    display:none;
}

.products-list .product-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.products-list .product-item a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #2D3E50;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="store-wrapper">
        <div class="category_list">
            <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Technical">Technical</a>
            <a href="#" class="category_item" category="Organizational">Organizational</a>

        </div>
        <section class="products-list">
            <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Equipment</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-item" category="Technical">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Tool</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-item" category="Organizational">
                <img src="~/images/100004-200.png" alt="">
                <a href="#">Material</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```